# Modify context from airflow task

Tags: python, airflow

I am developing an airflow operator. This operator should have a `on_success_callback` on the context, based on its run_id (if it starts with `manual_` or `scheduled_`).

So, basically, I'm successfully reading task context, however, I'm trying with no success to change the context from within my operator's code. Basically, that's what I'm trying:

```py
class MyOperator(BaseOperator):
   def __init__(self, ..., *kwargs):
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      ...

    def execute(self, context):
        dag_id = context["dag"].dag_id
        task_id = context["task"].task_id
        dr:DagRun = context["dag_run"]
        D:DAG = context["dag"]
        print(f"run_id is: {dr.run_id}")
        run_id = dr.run_id
        is_manual = run_id.startswith('manual__')
        is_scheduled = run_id.startswith('scheduled__')
        print(f"old context: {context['dag'].__dict__}")
        if is_manual:
            context['dag'].on_failure_callback = my_alert_function
            context['dag'].on_success_callback = my_alert_function
            context['dag'].params["opsgenie_team_name"] = "My Team"
        print(f"new context: {context['dag'].__dict__}")
        ...
```

Do you have any tips how can I modify a task context?